# How do you turn off rename feature when finished renaming in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, ide, automated-refactoring

In Netbeans whenever I use the Refactor->Rename option on a variable, I can't get it to turn off when I'm done. All instances of the variable stay highlighted, and I can't get them to stop being highlighted.

The biggest issue with this is that you can't edit any of the highlighted instances. Say for example I wanted to delete a line that happens to contain one of the instances. The rest of the line will delete, but the highlighted instance will stay there.

How do I stop the rename feature once I'm done with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, fortunately the solution is really simple: press enter.

Comment: I figured I would note that pressing 'Esc' works too